# The AllItems view not applied when add list to page as 'WebPart'

Tags: 2010, list, publishing

Im sure its pretty easy, but I dont know why its not working

I have a `custom list` with the default view `AllItems`, I have made some changes to this view (**through SPD**), every thing works fine in the default list's page `http://mysite/lists/mylist/AllItems.aspx`, but when I add the list as `webPart` to another page the `AllItems view` still shows the old view (as if its never been modified), even further I tried to create new `View` but nothing helped

Any suggestions guys?

Comment: Did you try editing the web part and changing the view from the web part properties? You can see a section to change the custom view selected.

Comment: @DeepuNair: Yes man, I already did, plus I tried to change it from the ribbon too, nothing helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround,
1-Go to the list's view in SPD (AllItems)
2-right click then `Edit in advance mode`
3-in the ribbon go to `Save web Part` section
4-then save the web part to the gallery as `to site gallery`

SPD will export the list's view as webpart, when you add it to a page it will renders as if its in the original page `http://mySite/Lists/MyList/AllItems.aspx`

Answer (score 0):

When adding a list webpart to a page it picks the View with BaseViewId=0 as the default. You can't access/modify that view using SPD only when you create the ListTemplate using Visual Studio.

If you look closely you'll see that it's not the original `AllItems` as it's usually using LinkTitleNoMenu instead of LinkTitle

If you're not creating a List Template using Visual studio, then your only option is to change the view after adding the web part to the page:

When web part is added to page in the browser select 'Edit Web Part' and then change view:
[image]

Comment: What do you suggest to workaround my issue?

Comment: If you're not creating a List Template using Visual studio, then your only option is to change the view after adding the web part to the page.

Comment: What do you mean by `change`? is it the modification i.e.:(SPD involved) over the default view or just changing the view it self  from lets say `AllItems` to `CustomView`?

Comment: See addition to answer

Comment: Ok per! your answer makes me feel incompetent, I tried what you suggest before I post this question, well thanks for your effort anyway, I know changing view must do the trick idk why its not working!!

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the view itself, or did you change the *web part* on the All Items page using SPD?  If you only changed the web part, the view has not changed, so any new web parts you add will still point to that original view.

To change the view, go into the ribbon or the drop down next to the view name and *modify this view*.

Comment: Yes, I changed the `AllItems.aspx` page using SPD